# laravel validation doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel

I am taking a laravel course an in order to follow the course I have to fix this issue, I checked everything, and apparently, everything is the same as the guy shows me. But the difference is that his validation works but not mine. It has to redirect me to the register_form when the validation is invalid but it doesn't.

Route

```
Route::get('/', function(){
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/register', 'HomeController@register_form');

Route::post('/register', 'HomeController@register');
```

Controller

```
namespace CoolBlog\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller {

    public function register_form(){
        return view('register');
    }

    public function register(Request $request) {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'username' => 'min:5|max:30',
            'email' => 'email',
            'pass' => 'min:5',
            'pass2' => 'same:pass'
        ]);
    }
}
```

Html Page

```
@extends('layout.default')

@section('title', 'Registration')

@section('content')
    <form method="post" action="/register" >
        {{csrf_field()}}
        Name: <input type="text" name="username"><br>
        E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
        Password: <input type="password" name="pass2"><br>
        Re-Password: <input type="password" name="pass2"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Register">
    </form>

@endsection
```

Comment: change `name` attribute of your first password field from `pass2` to `pass`

Comment: What course is this? Just a quick tips: do not use `_` in functions that are part of object (in this case `register_form`) use conventions, name your routes, use groups, use full names for variables instead of `pass` use `password`, try using `dd()` helper, in this example in `register` function in the end add `dd($request->all())` and see what you actually send... Good luck!

Comment: Ohh, it's my mistake I rewrite the form because I got frustrated, although I changed the name to pass the validation still doesn't work as it has to be

Comment: @Nikola Then please update the code in the question as well, so new people coming to this question can help you with the actual problem instead of directing you to that same name attribute of pass2 again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
Password: <input type="password" name="pass2"><br>
Re-Password: <input type="password" name="pass2"><br>
```

and replace it with this:

```
Password: <input type="password" name="pass"><br>
Re-Password: <input type="password" name="pass2"><br>
```

and in your validation if you want any field must be required then add required in the validation

```
$this->validate($request, [
            'username' => 'required|min:5|max:30',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'pass' => 'required|min:5',
            'pass2' => 'required|same:pass'
        ]);
```

Comment: I thought about that one too but I realized that when I submit an empty form the result must be the same as putting require in front of them because the validation form must return false at some point. However I tried that one but it still redirect to an empty page.

Comment: that's because you're not redirecting it anywhere.

change the function to this

public function register(Request $request) {
        $validator = $this->validate($request, [
            'username' => 'min:5|max:30',
            'email' => 'email',
            'pass' => 'min:5',
            'pass2' => 'same:pass'
        ]);
       if($validator->fails())
       {
          return redirect('YOUR_REDIRECTION ROUTE HERE');
       }

       // REGISTER USER HERE THE VALIDATION IS SUCCESSFUL
    }

Answer (score 0):

You are using same name for password and password confirmation. Change password name to pass in your blade file and try using this validation instead

```
$this->validate($request, [
        'username' => 'required|min:5|max:30',
        'email' => 'required|max:255|unique:users',
        'pass' => 'required|min:6|confirmed'
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw that you are not returning to any route after validating the form values. So, can you please try this code format. **the validation method is also updated on upper level laravel versions**

```
function store(Request $request)
    {
        request()->validate([
            'title' => 'required',
            'body' => 'required',
        ]);
        Post::create($request->all());
        return redirect()->route('posts.index')->with('success', 'Post created successfully');
```